# How to leave HTML tags as it is and change text in java string

Tags: java, string, replaceall

Want to leave HTML as it is in the Java String and to modify text

```
String input = "<center><b>0</b><i>i</i><h1>2</h1><h2>b</h2><h3>h</h3><h4>5</h4></center>";
    .replace("0", "۰").replace("1", "&#۱;").replace("2", "&#۲;")
    .replace("3", "&#۳;").replace("4", "&#۴;").replace("5", "&#۵;")
    .replace("b", "&#11;")
    .replace("i", "&#12;")
    .replace("h", "&#13;")
    .replace("c", "&#14;")
```

Its printing:

This code replacing all characters mentioned in `replace()` method
**Question:**
Can I NOT replace wriiten inside HTML tags and replace the text written outside html tags?

Please Note: The input string is dynamic but here I gave a static example

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why are you replacing??

Comment: As per the above comment: if you want to print the original string, don't replace the original string with the new and completely unrelated string "Hello HTML"?

Comment: If all you want to do is keep the HTML but replace the text then you need to do just that i.e. str.replace("Hello, World", "Hello HTML")

Comment: @DavidBrossard the output is dynamic how can I do that when I don't know what will be input?

Comment: By default String Objects are immutable......so, if you wanna modify some part of it you might wanna use string builder

Comment: `why are you replacing?? – Amimul Ehsan Rahi ` Its demand of my project.

Comment: Amimul Ehsan Rahi Why you are giving my question negative marks and positive marks to your answer `why are you replacing??`. Is there any reason?

Comment: I didn't give you any negative marks. And In stack overflow, it is not possible to upvote your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have three parts in the [A.replace(B, C)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,char)) function:
A - object which you are manipulating with
B - String to replace
C - String to replace B with
If you want to replace `World` in the `str` with `HTML`, then write so:
`str = str.replace("World", "HTML");`

Comment: Single quote doesn't work for a string in Java.

Comment: Damn, the language differences :). Thanks for the catch @ArvindKumarAvinash

Comment: @MikeB please pay attention to my question. I want to change only text by living HTML as it is and text in the string may be dynamic

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class TagsExtractClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TagsExtractClass markup = new TagsExtractClass();
        String text = "<b>Hello HTML</b>";

        ArrayList list;
        list = markup.storeTags(text);
        System.out.println("Content of HTML List:");
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Tag Number." + i + ": " + list.get(i));
        }
    }

    public ArrayList storeTags(String input) {
        ArrayList output = new ArrayList();

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<[^>]*>");

        Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

        boolean result = m.find();

        while (result) {
            output.add(m.group());
            input= input.substring(m.end(), input.length());
            m = p.matcher(input);
            result = m.find();
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your  code outputs only `Tag Number.0: <b>Tag Number.1: </b>` whereas I want to change only text by living HTML as it is

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for not giving concern:

Here is the simplest:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "<h1>Hello World</h1>";
        String[] array = str.split("<[^>]*>");

        String temp = null;

        for(String a : array)
        {
            if(!a.isEmpty()) {
                temp = a;
                break;
            }
        }

        str = str.replace(temp, "Hello HTML");
        System.out.println(str);
    }
```

Comment: @Murteza Hope it will help now :)

Comment: @Murteza If this answer helps you please accept the answer.

Comment: Your answer is near but not the exact solution what I am looking for e.g. If I add a two three tags and want to keep html as it is but when I changed text then your code not worked

Comment: I have updated my question to make it more clear. Please check

Comment: Don't mind but your ques is really not clear........

Comment: I am repeating my question that (1) I want to leave HTML in the string as its and (2) want to modify text that is outside HTML tags. Where I am not clear?